# What would be the best way of conveying the human quest for knowledge to sentient lifeforms

Tags: science-fiction, aliens

I am filling out an application for a competition called the [Broadcom MASTERS](https://student.societyforscience.org/broadcom-masters) and I have been asked a question:
"Imagine you are an astronaut exploring a new planet with alien life forms. As a representative of Earth, you are to present the aliens with three gifts from our planet. What items would you give and why?"
One of my ideas is to present them with something that conveyed the eternal human quest for knowledge of all that we see around us, but what would be the best item to do so?
EDIT: I already have the other two items made

Comment: This seems pretty broad and might be easier to answer if you limited it to just a single "branch" (or a few; it might be best to choose something that interests you) of knowledge.  Showing up with flint knappings, polio vaccine, and nanotubes might not send much of a message.  Congrats on being nominated!

Comment: I won't ask what the other two are but can you give a hint?

Comment: @ToddlesMcBerry I can actually give you both! The first is a form of art since humans throughout all of history have always made art. Music is one of the most universal art forms because anything that can make a sound can make music. I chose Beethoven's Symphony No. 5 because even if you don't know the name, pretty much everyone has heard of this song. The second was a comprehensive English dictionary with a brief history of human language and deep etymology tree for each word (like dictionary.com). The reason I chose English is because it's widely regarded as the 'universal language'.

Comment: I've probably been watching too many horror series, because my first idea on reading the question was a zombie groaning, "Brains!"

Comment: @Sharp_ do you have to give them just one Beethoven work?  I'd probably go for "iPod full of all classical music I could shove into the hard drive" or "stack of records of various music from Beethoven to the Beatles, Mozart to Sousa, and an additional stack of disks from eastern, middle eastern, and african music".  I don't know what the cargo constraints or technology constraints are, but I love your idea of showing the human experience and quest; providing a "history of music composition" says more than one recording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is only one gift, but I think it's a big one, and it leaves open two other gifts... but this gift speaks directly to your desire to communicate our thirst for expanding knowledge.

**An android tablet (or whatever open, stable computation platform makes sense to your situation), hooked into the Deep Deep Space Network, with a dump of Wikipedia, set to pereodically update.**  Even better if you can give them the protocol to the DDSN and Wikipedia along with the dump, so they can use their own tech to talk to it.

OK, this might be a silly idea, you could always use any electronic encyclopaedia, but a Wikipedia dump would give sentient life forms (especially whatever their equivalent of "librarian", "archivist", or the like is) many benefits:

- The first level of the Wikipedia palimpsest is, of course, the articles, from Amy Rose to Z-Boson.  This will show the broad interests of our species, and our desire to know everything, even things others may find trivial.
- The second level is that the "scholarship" employed on articles about "Warp Core (Star Trek)" and "Amy Rose" would show that, even for fictional subjects, our innate desire to collect and organize knowledge of the universe is unbounded.  We show the same zest for knowledge in all forms, from medicine to fictional religions... with the implication that we'd have an entire sub-wiki dedicated to anything these new aliens would give us.
- The third level would show the science we have related directly to organizing knowledge.  We are such an inquisitive species that it's impossible for one being to know "everything" of our science and knowledge, and therefore we had to design systems to organize knowledge.  From our incessant categorizing, our complex tagging, and our hypermedia systems, we can show that we not only like to know things, but we also like to know how we know things.
- The fourth level is the article history.  Alien Archivists would be very interested to see how our knowledge has changed over time, and a full dump of Wikipedia contains the entire history of every article on the system.  Our knowledge of the climate and the stars have expanded brilliantly, and the history of the "Black Hole" article would be just as engaging as the final product.
- The sixth level would be introducing these alinens to the Meta pages.  Oh yes, the content may not be the most edifying of ourselves as a species, but they would see the zest and zeal our species has for, not only seeking out the truth, but discussing and arguing various interpretations of the truth.  Tied into the history, Archivists would be able to divine how various types of edits happen to our knowledgebase, and how we decide what's a "belief," what's "trolling," and what's "notable."
- The final level, however, I think is the coolest:  it's the edit link.  By tying the computer into the Deep Deep Space Network, we, as a species, would be inviting them, as a species, to expand our knowledgebase.  Wikipedia's "Be Bold!" policy says more about our desire to expand our knowledge than just about anything else... Wikipedia says:  "Even if you're wrong, even if we don't like what you edit, go ahead and do it!  We'll clean it up later if we have to!"

You get some of the benefits above with a regular encyclopaedia.  Maybe an electronic version of every published encyclopaedia through the years might provide most of the benefits, but I think they as a species, and we as a species, would benefit best with an editable dump, and the encouragement to help us expand our knowledge from the comfort of whatever their species uses as a desk really says something about us as a species.

Comment: I admit if I read the question as assuming the aliens read English and wanted just the end product, I'd +1 but what about the other two items?  Is there something that might show how we have developed and progressed in our questions for knowledge?  To use role-playing games as a reference, Wikipedia is your character sheet; our quest for knowledge is the pages of background.

Comment: Thank you! Though Wikipedia isn't considered a 'scholarly source', it does also highlight other things about human nature that you wouldn't get from a distilled science encyclopedia. The misinformation conveys we're not perfect, the pranks include humans attraction to humor and practical jokes along with many other things.

Comment: Exactly, @Sharp_.  I would use the other two items to, perhaps, provide context, or provide a more "scholarly source," but Wikipedia, in a single "item" or "gift", encapsulates so much of the Human experience, from knowledge to trolling, it just seems too good to pass up.

Comment: The constraint of only three items makes this really difficult, @ToddlesMcBerry. There's so much to say about the Human Experience, it's hard to whittle it down to three things, which I think is the whole point of the question. Our hypothetical astronaut has to communicate with the aliens somehow; I'm assuming that they are on an equivalent level of development as we are, otherwise any sort of communication, even gift exchange, would be difficult.

Comment: One benefit of Wikipedia, @ToddlesMcBerry, is that it contains so many broad subjects that, even if this intelligent species doesn't understand English at any level, they will be able to find SOMETHING they recognize;  math, elements, star charts... every archivist on their side would find SOMETHING they recognize, which they could then use as a Rosetta Stone or ... maybe the decipherment of the Maya language is more on point for my intent.

Comment: You're right.  After thinking about it, with all the languages and articles, it might be a Rosetta Stone in itself.